# Change parameter at form load and close

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I am writing this application in C#. I need to send a value when I open an edit form to my SQL table that contains a bit value. A value of 1 represents open, and a value of 0 represents closed. I need to pass a 1 when I open the edit form for this record, and put a 0 there when I leave the form. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to update a value in a database?  Are you asking how to listen to events on a form (such as loading the form or closing the form)?  What have you tried and where specifically are you stuck?

Comment: @David I need to know how to set a '1' in the cell when the form Loads and then, in the close, set a 0 again. Just pass the value and then put a 0 back...

Comment: In *what* "cell"?  In the database?  If you're asking how to update a value in a database then there are many, many tutorials and examples for that.  What have you tried?  Maybe start here?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, in the database. I just need to pass this value when the form is open, then dispose that. I know how to do that by Updates, one update to set "1" in the form load and an UPDATE to set it "0" in the form closed. I just wanted to know if someone could help me to do something better...

Comment: Take a look at my answer. You don't necessarily need two separate updates, you can create one update function that will take a given parameter. Writing that update code twice just to change one value would be quite a hassle. If that's what you already have, and your question really is about the efficiency, I would post the code you have and let us see why it might be inefficient.

Comment: @McAdam331 many thanks! I've figured it out! Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle this in the Load and Closed event handlers.

When you open, you can have this:

```
public myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call function to do bit set, or set it here.
    setBit(1, rowNumber);
}
```

And then closed is almost identical:

```
public myForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    setBit(0, rowNumber);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT** I am sort of making the assumption that your issue is *when and where* to set this bit, and not *how*. If you are having trouble with writing the query to set this bit, let me know. But a function for it would look something like this:

```
private setBit(int open, int rowID)
{
    using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs)) // Assuming you've already built the connection string.
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tableName SET columnName = @open WHERE rowID = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@open", open);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowID);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Of course, good practice would be to put this in a Try/Catch block, but I just wanted to cover this too in case this also gave you trouble.

**EDIT 2**
I have edited the code above. Note that you are going to be changing the open/close value of a specific row (at least, that's how the question appears) so you will need to find a way to get that row ID and pass it into your `setBit` function, because you will need it in there `WHERE` clause of your SQL statement to update the proper row. I would challenge yourself to figure out how to get that row ID, and if you get stuck, feel free to come back for help.

Comment: Anyways, I need to have an UPDATE in those functions right?

Comment: Yes, I actually JUST updated this haha. Take a look, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Okay. Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: It's working! I've created a global function with your code and in the edtition form i've made a read() to a int the rowID. It's working fine :D thank you

Comment: Awesome. Feel free to upvote and accept later on if it remains the best answer, and don't hesitate to ask for help in the future too.

Comment: No it's not... it only works one time! :\ If I open the same record  twice the update don't work :\

Comment: What's happening the second time?

Comment: OUCH MY BAD. It's working now :\ my mistake, i've made a copy paste and forgot to change 0 to 1 in the form load! All right now! Many thanks :D

Comment: Anytime. Again, feel free to upvote and accept the answer, only if it works that is, because you never know when it could help someone else. Best of luck moving forward.

Comment: Many thanks! But just one thing, if I wish to pass the table name too? Like a parameter? Is it possible?